# Best Practices for small changes from Quality to Production

Tags: javascript, best-practices

I am at a new job, and how they manage development and then deployment to production is strange. So, I was curious what is the best practice for this scenario?

A user just wanted a form field to have bolded and larger text. It turns out the issue from a previous developer was in the javascript file they had in the "Site Assets". I made a change in the .js file, in the Quality Servers. UAT was done, issue resolved. Well, the way they deploy this to production is just manually editing the .js file in the Production server in Designer. What is best practice for something so small?

Creating a feature, or solution for that does seem unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. Creating a feature or solution for something like this is pretty unnecessary. If the changes in your non-production environment test out fine, I would just make a copy of the js file in the Prod 'Site Assets' library, and copy over the one from your non-prod environment.

Comment: Or better yet, enable versioning in the site assets library if it isn't already, and save the edited js file as the next version of the current one. That way, you can always revert back to the one that works in prod if necessary.

Comment: copying over is difficult, we copy pasted the contents, this way we could maintain versioning, incase someone fat-fingered a mistake.

Comment: Typically, I download the file from our non-prod environment to my local drive and then re-upload to prod as a new version. But copy pasting works just as well. :)

Comment: In addition to enable versioning in the library: We keep such "small" bits of code like single JavaScript files or small but helpful PowerShell scripts in an additional SVN repository next to our "big" C#-repository. So we can track changes like the same way we do in our C#-solutions and keep the files even if customer's site is deleted (in case the next customer wants to have the same or similar functionality).